# How can I extract data from the ItemPaged iterator into a dict or list?

Tags: python, azure

I am very new to Python and coding in general. I've established an API connection to an Azure endpoint to extract management group/subscription information. Running the code snip below, the output gets printed which looks to be a dict. I'm confused at how to feed that data into a useable dict or list.

If I create a newlist and add newlist.append(item), the data contained is not the subscription data but "[<azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2021_01_01.models._models_py3.Subscription object at 0x000401DE26902950>]"

But if I run the code below as is with print(item), the relevant subscription info is printed in the console. What am I doing wrong? TIA for tips to point me in the right direction.

```
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient

    def get_subscriptions():
        client = SubscriptionClient(
            credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        )
        response = client.subscriptions.list()

        for item in response:
            print(item)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        get_subscriptions()
```

Running the code snip, I see all of the subscription data via print(item) under the For loop. I was expecting to be able to append the data into a list under the Loop to get the data I need. But the results returned [<azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2021_01_01.models._models_py3.Subscription obj.....] in the list instead of subscription data that is seen via print(item).

Comment: reponse is a list of objects with type azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2021_01_01.models._models_py3.Subscription. Python objects - this one included - can have a method called repr which prints something humanly intelligible when you attempt to print the object. Without looking at the documentation, it sounds like the repr prints some attributes which you're interested in. You should read the documentation and decide which attributes you're interested in, and put those into your own dict instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in your list are objects of type `azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2021_01_01.models._models_py3.Subscription`. You can find documentation on this object [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2021_01_01.models.subscription?view=azure-python).

As [Matt Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13859974/matt-smith) mentioned, the `print` method uses the object representation. And in this case, it does something like `print(item.display_name)`.